Check if the given image is a crop of another bigger image
I have some images. In that some images are cropped versions.
like here is the original image big image
and the cropped image small image.
Note that the shape(resolution) of images are not same.
I have a few pairs like this. The original images are kept in a folder and the cropped images are kept in another folder.
Ultimately I want to find the pairs of original image and cropped image from these images.
So I want to iterate to the images from both folders and check if the cropped image is a part of bigger image or not.
But I can't find any algorithm that giving such results with images of different shapes(resolutions).
I have already tried cv2.matchTemplate and skimage.metrics.structural_similarity
but they are only working for images of similar shape(resolution).

@ChristophRackwitz yes, but the case here is different.

not substantially. just because you want a "simple yes/no" answer from an algorithm doesn't mean you can expect such an algorithm to become simpler. the cognitive parts of the task (any kind of feature extraction and matching) don't go away. -- since you already rejected the one answer given below, I must wonder what answer would satisfy you. -- you complained about the visualization. why? you can just not visualize the process. SO is not for solving your assignment, it's for helping you solve your assignment.

@ChristophRackwitz No, I am not talking about yes/no case I mean previously no any question has different dimensions as you can see the vertical dimension are not same for both image still they exactly match vertically. And even the horizontal dimension of cropped image is not similar to the horizontal dimensions of the part in bigger image. So I guess this is the unique case.
And about the visualization I already appreciated the answerer, but I just asked for a simpler implementation because I don't need visualization in my project.

@ChristophRackwitz
And also if you don't have any answers to give just stop making this type of hate comments. I know you are doing it for improve your profile. But this is not the good way.


Finds similarities between two images using SIFT. Retrieves well-matched points and uses these points to identify the cut region in the original image

import cv2
import numpy as np


image1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')

sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image2, None)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
good_matches = [m for m, n in matches if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance]

if len(good_matches) > 50:

    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    
    M, _ = cv2.findHomography(dst_pts, src_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    
    h, w = image2.shape[:2]
    pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h-1], [w-1, h-1], [w-1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)
    image1 = cv2.polylines(image1, [np.int32(dst)], True, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    
    cv2.imshow('Result', cv2.resize(image1, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Result:

Update
In this code snippet, the expression 0.75 * n.distance represents a threshold value that is used to filter out good matches during the feature matching process. This value is obtained by multiplying the distance of the second nearest neighbor (n) by 0.75.
The threshold value 0.1 * n.distance determines how far away a match must be relative to the second closest match. The smaller this value, the stricter the match criterion is applied, leading to fewer matches. Hence, the number of matches in the good_matches list decreases.
On the other hand, if you use a larger threshold value, such as 0.75 * n.distance, the algorithm will accept more matches, because in this case the match criterion is less stringent. As a result, more matches are accepted and the number of matches in the good_matches list increases.
Therefore, as you increase the threshold value, you get more matches because the matching criteria is more relaxed. The smaller the threshold value, the fewer matches you get because the matching criteria become stricter. This is a parameter used to control the precision and accuracy of the match between two images.
0.1 = 90% similarity
total_matches:  17264
matches_with_thresh :  73
90% similarity:


0.75 = 25% similarity
total_matches:  17264
matches_with_thresh :  3789
25% similarity:

Sample img
0.1 = 90% similarity
total_matches:  17264
matches_with_thresh :  0
90% similarity Sample img:


0.75 = 25% similarity
total_matches:  17264
matches_with_thresh :  26
25% similarity Sample img:

import cv2

image1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')
# image2 = cv2.imread('sample_img.jpg')

sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

matches_with_thresh = [m for m, n in matches if m.distance < 0.1 * n.distance]
matches_count = len(matches_with_thresh)
total_matches = len(matches)
print("total_matches: ", total_matches)
print("matches_with_thresh : ", matches_count)

img_matches = cv2.drawMatches(image1, kp1, image2, kp2, matches_with_thresh, None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

cv2.imshow('Good Matches', cv2.resize(img_matches, (0, 0), fx=0.3, fy=0.3))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Thanks for your help but I just need to know that if the smaller image is a part of bigger image or not. (maybe just True/False or similarity in percentage like 88%)
I don't need the visualization of where the crop has been located in the bigger image.

Cross correlation is probably what you want for this.

Thanks again for your updated explanation.
But what if i just want to know if the smaller image is the part of bigger image or not.
Means in True / False only.

what if? then you still need all these computations anyway because there's no cheaper way to do it. were you expecting anything simpler than this?

You can query with the if else block by looking at the matches_count value. The important thing here is how sensitive you need to work.
By keeping the threshold value high, you can get True False in case of any match.
if matches_count > 1:
print("Images are similar")
else:
print("Images are not similar")

@TwoPoint Thankyou very much, I've got my final answer.
You have helped me a lot. I have another question for which I didn't get any answer yet. If you can please give it a try here
